# Datatable no regresa la primera fila de la consulta, C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Estoy tratando de imprimir en consola dos columnas de una consulta de `MySQL` mediante el siguiente código:

```
public void cargarHorario()
    {
        DataTable tabla1 = new DataTable();
        maestro.NoMaestro = 23041;
        tabla1.Load(DAOMaestro.seleccionarHorarioMaestro(maestro));

        int noFilas = tabla1.Rows.Count;
        Console.WriteLine(noFilas.ToString());

        for (noFilas = 0; noFilas < tabla1.Rows.Count; noFilas++)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine($"{tabla1.Rows[noFilas]["dia"].ToString()} {tabla1.Rows[noFilas]["hora"].ToString()}");
        } 
    }
```

El problema es que al correr la aplicación me genera un error del tipo `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Sin embargo, al obtener el número total de filas con `tabla1.Rows.Count` me di cuenta de que esto regresa siempre un valor menos el resultado de mi consulta. Si envío una que me debe dar 18, mi count es de 17. Por otra parte, al ver los resultados de consola, el primer renglón de la consulta no está, la impresión empieza a partir del segundo. ¿Alguien sabe lo que puede estar pasando?

Mi código donde obtengo la consulta es:

```
public static MySqlDataReader seleccionarHorarioMaestro(Maestro maestro)
    {
        string instruccionSQL = $@"select * from materias_grupos_horario
                                   inner join
                                   materias_grupo on claveMateriaHorario = claveMateriaGrupo
                                   and grupoMateriaHorario = grupo
                                   inner join
                                   maestros on noMaestroGrupo = noMaestro
                                   where
                                   noMaestro = @noMaestro;";

        MySqlCommand consulta = ejecutarConsulta(instruccionSQL);
        asignarParametros(consulta, maestro);
        MySqlDataReader reader = consulta.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        return reader;
    }

public static void asignarParametros(MySqlCommand consulta, Maestro maestro)
    {
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noMaestro", maestro.NoMaestro);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombreMaestro", maestro.NombreMaestro);
    }

 public static MySqlCommand ejecutarConsulta(string sentenciaSQL)
    {
        using (MySqlCommand consulta = new MySqlCommand(sentenciaSQL, ConexionBDSingleton.Conexion))
        {
            ConexionBDSingleton.Conexion.ClearAllPoolsAsync();
            return consulta;
        }
    }
```

Y la conexión la estoy realizando mediante un singleton:

```
class ConexionBDSingleton
{
    private static MySqlConnection instancia = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    private ConexionBDSingleton() { }

    public static MySqlConnection Conexion
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instancia == null)
                {
                    MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IngenieriaDB"].ToString());

                    conexion.Open();
                    return conexion;
                }
                return instancia;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El error `IndexOutOfRangeException` esta en que en tu iteración en algún momento excedes los límites de la matriz.

Mi sugerencia es que hagas un `foreach` dejará más limpio tu código:

```
foreach (DataRow row in tabla1.Rows)
    Console.WriteLine($"{row["dia"].ToString()} {row["hora"].ToString()}");
```

La estructura de control `foreach` sirve para moverse por los elementos de una estructura de datos, como podría ser un vector, y realizar acciones para cada una de los elementos ya definidos por lo que no necesitas indicar el indice dentro de la matriz.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario del foreach, sin embargo, lo he usado y mi resultado es el mismo con respecto a la impresión de valores; empiezan a partir la segunda fila de mi consulta, tengo perdida la primera.

Comment: El problema esta en el query entonces muestra la estructura y la información de tus tablas.

Comment: Si  copio y pego el query en mysql funciona, por eso sé el número de filas que me debe dar y que me falta que se imprima la primera fila. Ya cambié en la instrucción la variable por un valor estático. Pasa lo mismo: en una consulta deben salir un total de 15 rows, pero el `tabla1.Rows.Count` me regresa 14. Al imprimir en consola, me aparecen los datos del dataTable: 3 9, 4 14... Cuando según mi consulta, deben empezar por: 1 8, 3 9, 4 14... Por otro lado, en la publicación ya estaban puestos los métodos donde hago al consulta y conexión a la base de datos. No sé si es eso a lo que te refieres.